# Pymongo importing succeeded but not showing in the collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I tried importing json file which succeeded

```
mongoimport --db dbwhy --collection dbcol --jsonArray consumer_complaint.json
2016-01-15T19:00:42.277-0600    connected to: localhost
2016-01-15T19:00:42.320-0600    imported 34 documents
```

but when I tried viewing it, it was not there

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client['dbwhy']
coll = db['dbcol']
curs = db.coll.find()
for i in curs:
    print(i)
```

It does not show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
db.coll.find()
```

This would find all documents inside the *`coll` collection*, but *your collection is named `dbcol`*.

Instead, use the `coll` variable that you've already defined:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)

db = client['dbwhy']
coll = db['dbcol']

curs = coll.find()  # FIX is here
for i in curs:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It worked. Can't believe I made such a silly mistake