# im not able to view my records which is available in collection using pymongo with aadhar datasets

Tags: pymongo

I'm trying to process my aadhardataset using pymongo. I have done queries using normal sample documents  when I processed with my datasets the records is not visible , but my collection contains 400k records which is available in aadhardataset. I am able to count the number of records in my collection but I'm not able to view my records.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('/home/hadoop/Downloads/aadhar.csv')
    database = client.database 
    collect = database.collect  
    result = database.collect.insert_many([{'df': i} for i in                  range(418068)]) 
    database.collect.count()
```

I'm getting the count as 418 068 which is there in aadhardataset

When I'm using this below condition to view single document it's not working

```
import pprint
    pprint.pprint(collect.find_one())
```

I'm not able to view my records which available in collections

Comment: Please refer this soultion suits your problem as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822568/pymongo-importing-succeeded-but-not-showing-in-the-collection?rq=1

Comment: It is generating only the id of records but it is not showing the content of the record